What do I use for my DIY backend page to save and re-render html codes for blog posts saved on postgres database as text?
I am trying to build a backend dashboard page for my own blog post website. I save the blog post body as text in my postgres database. But when I go to the frontend, it's not rendering the html code as expected but just as a text.
How do I solve this? Or What do you guys use?
Thank you in advance!
I have no idea what to try.

Hard to debug your code without code

Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with issues, but there are some expectation of you. Please spend a few minuets to Take the Tour and review [ask]. Then update your question to include table definition(s) (DDL), sample data, and expected results. All as formatted text or even better a fiddle, but - no images.

I'd like to know just the process or the library used to do it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Thanks for your help guys... I got it from a youtube video. Thanks to the creator for his generosity to share his accumulated knowledge freely.

I need a package/library called richtext(e.g buttercms).
I'm sorry for not being able to provide codes as I thought
it's irrelevent to my problems.
